# Backend: where to define dropdown attribute's list of values

Tags: attributes, multiselect-attribute

I am trying to define attribute 'hello' with values 'hello1', 'hello2', and 'hello3'
in the Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Add New Attribute. In the
"Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" field I enter "Multiple Select" but I am
unable to see where the place where I can enter the three values
'hello1', 'hello2', and 'hello3' is.

Can anyone please help with this simple question which I am guessing
must have an obvious answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ON the left there should be 2 tabs. Check the second tab. From that one you should be able to set the attribute label for all store views and the attribute options if the attribute supports options. If that tab is missing then there is something wrong with your Magento instance.

Comment: Thanks, indeed when I select "Multiple Select" for "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" a new div appears under the "Manage Label / Options" tab as you suggested allowing me to define the set of options.